# Three colors triangles

Tags: c, math, probability, factorial

I am trying to make a code for this problem:

> (Source: https://www.codewars.com/kata/insane-coloured-triangles/train/c)
>
> A coloured triangle is created from a row of colours, each of which is
>   red, green or blue. Successive rows, each containing one fewer colour
>   than the last, are generated by considering the two touching colours
>   in the previous row. If these colours are identical, the same colour
>   is used in the new row. If they are different, the missing colour is
>   used in the new row. This is continued until the final row, with only
>   a single colour, is generated.
>
> For example, different possibilities are:
>
> ```
> Colour here:            G G        B G        R G        B R 
> Becomes colour here:     G          R          B          G 
>
> With a bigger example:
>    R R G B R G B B  
>     R B R G B R B
>      G G B R G G
>       G R G B G
>        B B R R
>         B G R
>          R B
>           G
> ```
>
> You will be given the first row of the triangle as a string and its your job to return the final colour which would appear in the bottom row as a string. In the case of the example above, you would be given `'RRGBRGBB'`, and you should return `'G'`.
>
> Constraints:
>
> ```
> 1 <= length(row) <= 10 ** 5
> ```
>
> The input string will only contain the uppercase letters '`B', 'G' or 'R'`.
>
> The exact number of test cases will be as follows:
>
> ```
> 100 tests of 100 <= length(row) <= 1000 
> 100 tests of 1000 <= length(row) <= 10000 
> 100 tests of 10000 <= length(row) <= 100000
> ```
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> triangle('B') == 'B'
> triangle('GB') == 'R'
> triangle('RRR') == 'R'
> triangle('RGBG') == 'B'
> triangle('RBRGBRB') == 'G'
> triangle('RBRGBRBGGRRRBGBBBGG') == 'G'
> ```

So I have made this code and it works for all the sample tastes but when it comes for `length of row > 25` it fails due my factorial function,and the length in some cases is up to `100,000`, so any suggestion to fix this problem at least any mathematic formula that can solve the problem or a small hint.

by the way I have made this code after I found a mathematic way to solve the problem in this site :

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257158/three-color-triangle-challenge

```
long long factorial(long long num)     
{
    long long fact = num;

    if (fact == 0)
        fact = 1;

    while (num > 1)
    {
        num--;
        fact *= num;
    }
    return (fact);
}

long long combination(long long n, long long k, long long fact_n)
{
    long long fact_k = factorial(k);
    long long comb = ( fact_n / (fact_k * factorial(n - k)) );
    return (comb);
}

char triangle(const char *row)
{
    long long len = strlen(row);
    long long n = len - 1;
    long long k = 0;
    int sign = pow(-1,n);
    long long sum = 0;
    char *result = "RGB";
    int a;
    long long fact_n = factorial(n);

    while (k < len)                 //This while calculate Segma (∑). 
    {
        if (row[k] == 'R')
            a = 0;
        else if (row[k] == 'G')
            a = 1;
        else if (row[k] == 'B')
            a = 2;

        if (a != 0)
            sum = sum + (combination(n,k,fact_n) * a); 
        k++;
    }

    sum = sign * (sum % 3);

    if (sum == -1 || sum == -2)
        sum += 3;

  return (result[sum]);
}
```

Comment: `long long` cannot hold a very large factorial. Perhaps you can find a way to cancel out numbers in the numerator and denominator to avoid conputing such large numbers, before the division.

Comment: I believe that this is a different kata for a good reason. To solve this one you need some better math than the one you are using now.

Comment: Hint: [modulo arithmetic rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Equivalences).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, could you please elaborate a bit? 3 is not a huge prime so for `length(row) <= 10 ** 5` there will be a lot of divisions by various numbers not co-prime with 3. I don't see any easy workaround for this. If you see, I'm very interested in those ideas.

Comment: Please don't post questions that rely on external links. Explain the problem *in the question itself.*

Comment: Why call `combination` if `a` is zero? It's lengthy and the final result will be zero because it's multiplied by zero.

Comment: `n` is invariant, so `factorial(n)` is invariant (i.e. cache it). Since `k` is incremented, you can probably calculate `factorial(k)` from `k * factorial(k - 1)` [which you cache]. Likewise, for `factorial(n - k)`

Comment: @CraigEstey It will not work with k = 1000.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I will assume that the formula in the link you provided is correct:

[image]

---

In order to avoid integer overflow, we will need to apply these [modulo arithmetic rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Equivalences):

```
(a * b) mod c = ((a mod c) * (b mod c)) mod c

(a ± b) mod c = ((a mod c) ± (b mod c)) mod c
```

Applying them to the formula:

[image]

---

> But how do we calculate
>
> [image]
>
> ... without directly calculating the coefficient itself (which can cause overflow)?

Since 3 is a prime number, this can be accomplished with **[Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem)**:

[image]

... where `n_i, m_i` are the `i`-th digits of `n, m` in *base-3*.

---

Conversion to base-3 is easy with integer division:

```
// convert a number to base 3
// and returns the number of digits
unsigned conv_base_3(unsigned n, unsigned max, unsigned* out)
{
    unsigned i = 0;
    while (i < max && n > 0)
    {
        out[i] = n % 3;
        n /= 3;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Note that since `n_i, m_i` are always in the range `[0, 2]` (because they are base-3 digits), `C(n_i, m_i)` are very easy to calculate:

```
// calculate the binomial coefficient for n < 3
unsigned binom_max_2(unsigned n, unsigned k)
{
    if (n < k)
        return 0;
    switch (n)
    {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            return 1;
        case 2:
            return 1 + (k == 1);

        // shouldn't happen
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

And now the theorem itself:

```
// Lucas's theorem for p = 3
unsigned lucas_3(unsigned len_n, const unsigned * dig_n,
                 unsigned len_k, const unsigned * dig_k)
{
    // use modulo product rule:
    // prod[i] % 3 = ((prod[i - 1] % 3) * value[i])      
    unsigned prod = 1;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < len_n; i++) {
        unsigned n_i = dig_n[i];
        unsigned k_i = (i < len_k) ? dig_k[i] : 0;
        prod = (prod * binom_max_2(n_i, k_i)) % 3;
    }
    return prod % 3;
}
```

Character conversion:

```
// convert from 012 to RGB
char int_2_char(int i)
{
    switch (i) {
        case 0: return 'R';
        case 1: return 'G';
        case 2: return 'B';

        // shouldn't happen
        default:
            return '\0';
    }
}

// convert from RGB to 012
unsigned char_2_int(char c)
{
    switch (c) {
        case 'R': return 0;
        case 'G': return 1;
        case 'B': return 2;

        // shouldn't happen
        default:
            return 3;
    }
}
```

Finally, the triangle algorithm:

```
// the problem constraints state that n <= 10 ** 5
// max number of base-3 digits
#define MAX_N_LOG_3 11

// main algorithm function
char triangle(const char * input)
{
    unsigned sum = 0;
    const int n = strlen(input);

    // calculate digits of n - 1
    unsigned dig_n[MAX_N_LOG_3];
    unsigned len_n = conv_base_3(n - 1, MAX_N_LOG_3, dig_n);

    for (unsigned km1 = 0; km1 < n; km1++)
    {
        // calculate digits of k - 1
        unsigned dig_k[MAX_N_LOG_3];
        unsigned len_k = conv_base_3(km1, MAX_N_LOG_3, dig_k);

        // calculate C(n - 1, k - 1) mod 3
        unsigned Cnk_mod3 = lucas_3(len_n, dig_n, len_k, dig_k);

        // add using the modulo rule
        sum = (sum + Cnk_mod3 * char_2_int(input[km1])) % 3;
    }

    // value of (-1) ** (n - 1)
    // no need for pow; just need to know if n is odd or even
    int sign = (n % 2) * 2 - 1;

    // for negative numbers, must resolve the difference
    // between C's % operator and mathematical mod
    int sum_mod3 = (3 + (sign * (int)(sum % 3))) % 3;
    return int_2_char(sum_mod3);
}
```

The above code passes all tests. Note that it was written in favor of clarity, not performance.

---

So why was this code able to pass all tests in the allocated time, whereas the simple table-based approach wasn't? Because of its *time complexity*:

- The table-based approach processes all levels of the triangle, which is **`O(n^2)`** (see [Triangle Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)).
- Of course, using Lucas's algorithm, only the top level has to be processed; however the algorithm itself is `O(log n)`, because it loops through every digit of `n` (regardless of the base). The overall complexity is **`O(n log n)`**, which still represents a significant improvement.

Comment: Aha, I see it works because there is no division after additions. Didn't take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const triangle = row => {
  let reduced = row.length > 1 ? '' : row;
  for (let i = 0; i < row.length - 1; i += 1) {
    reduced += row[i] == row[i + 1] ? row[i] : 'RGB'.replace(row[i], '').replace(row[i + 1], '');
  }
  return reduced.length > 1 ? triangle(reduced) : reduced;
}
```

```html
triangle('B') == 'B'
triangle('GB') == 'R'
triangle('RRR') == 'R'
triangle('RGBG') == 'B'
triangle('RBRGBRB') == 'G'
triangle('RBRGBRBGGRRRBGBBBGG') == 'G'
```

```html
const triangle = row => {
  let reduced = row.length > 1 ? '' : row;
  for (let i = 0; i < row.length - 1; i += 1) {
    reduced += row[i] == row[i+1] ? row[i] : 'RGB'.replace(row[i], '').replace(row[i+1], '');
  }
  return reduced.length > 1 ? triangle(reduced) : reduced;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is of little use here since you never have to return to a previous state. Iteration is a better solution and can be done rather simply.

The changes to the initial string can also be made in-place since you never need to return to an original value once it's used and changed.

The method is as follows. As long as the string is larger than one character, process each set of two characters (overlapping) in the original.

For that pair, change the first character based on your rules. When all pairs are done, remove the last character from the string, resulting in a string with one less character.

Here's some sample code that shows this in action, with unnecessary but useful checks and output functions:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Helper function to output nicely spaced string.

static void output(int gap, char *str) {
    // Spaces at line start.

    while (gap-- > 0)
        putchar(' ');

    // Actual string with spaces between letters, end line following.

    while (*str != '\0') {
        putchar(' ');
        putchar(*str++);
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

// The meat of the solution.

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Check parameter count and content.

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "*** Needs one argument\n");
        return 1;
    }

    size_t strSz = strlen(argv[1]);
    if (strSz == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "*** Argument too short\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("String size is %ld\n", strSz);
    int debug = (strSz <= 20);

    for (char *str = argv[1]; *str != '\0'; str++) {
        if (*str == 'R' || *str == 'G' || *str == 'B')
            continue;
        fprintf(stderr, "*** Bad character '%c' found\n", *str);
        return 1;
    }

    // Continue until you have a short enough string.

    int spaces = 0;
    while (strSz > 1) {
        // Output current string, update spaces for next.

        char *str = argv[1];
        if (debug)
            output(spaces++, str);

        // Process each overlapping pair in string.

        while (*str != '\0') {
            if      (*str == 'G' && *(str + 1) == 'R') *str = 'B';
            else if (*str == 'R' && *(str + 1) == 'G') *str = 'B';
            else if (*str == 'B' && *(str + 1) == 'G') *str = 'R';
            else if (*str == 'G' && *(str + 1) == 'B') *str = 'R';
            else if (*str == 'B' && *(str + 1) == 'R') *str = 'G';
            else if (*str == 'R' && *(str + 1) == 'B') *str = 'G';

            str++;
        }
        *(str - 1) = '\0';
        strSz--;
    }

    // Output final one-character string.

    if (debug)
        output(spaces, argv[1]);
    else
        puts(argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of that code when run with the argument `RRGBRGBB` is, as expected:

```
String size is 8
 R R G B R G B B
  R B R G B R B
   G G B R G G
    G R G B G
     B B R R
      B G R
       R B
        G
```

It also works with strings up to the limit (100,000 characters) but keep in mind it's an O(n<sup>2</sup>) solution so will slow down as the sizes get larger. A test run on a random 100,000-character string managed to complete in just under 15 seconds so, if it needs to be faster than that, this solution won't be suitable. For completeness, here's a table of run-time for various input sizes on my system (debug output disabled):

```
Input size   Run time
----------   --------
         1    0.001 s
        10    0.002 s
       100    0.002 s
      1000    0.005 s
     10000    0.141 s
    100000   14.331 s
```

It crosses the one-second threshold somewhere between 20,000 and 30,000 characters.

Comment: Yeah I Have done your idea before and worked just with sample tastes but when the length of row become 100,000 the compiler give me run out of time :/

Comment: Downvote. The code in this answer is O(n^2). It probably works for https://www.codewars.com/kata/coloured-triangles , but not for https://www.codewars.com/kata/insane-coloured-triangles , where the input is much larger and you'll need recursion or factorials or some other tricks to massively reduce your big-O complexity. The question is about the latter problem, not the former.

Comment: @jcsahnwaldt: Optimised the code a little but t still may not be suitable for the website in the link. There's no obvious indicator there (or in this question) that it needs to run in a certain time (unless that's only stated once you join).  Hopefully, the info added will make people aware of the limitations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll remove my downvote. You don't have to log in on Codewars to test the code. Just click on https://www.codewars.com/kata/insane-coloured-triangles/train/c and paste it in. Here's a version of your code that has the required API: https://gist.github.com/jcsahnwaldt/c059df6eee99794c9551cd9f6c3dcb7a

Answer (score 0):

```
def triangle(x):
l =len(x)
v=l
R=""

for j in range(v-1):
    for i in range(l-1):
        la=[x[i],x[i+1]]
        if x[i]==x[i+1]:
            R+=x[i]
        else:
            if "R" not in la:
                R+= "R"
            elif "G" not in la:
                R+= "G"
            else:
                R+= "B"
    x=R    
    R=""
    l=len(x)
return (x)
```