# Can you help me decreasing my code time execution?

Tags: python, colors, rgb

I am doing an exercise on Codewars and the exercice (kata in their language) consist of returning a letter, R G or B after a few operation. We are given a string like this : RGBGBRRB. We have to make a sort of inverted pyramid... Each new row of the pyramid is built like this:[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOSVy.png)

So if colours are RG: it result B, if colours are BR: it result G; etc... And if the two colours are same, it result the colour in question. If you hadn't understood, I put link of the exercise [-here-](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a331ea7ee1aae8f24000175/train/python)...

Here is my code, from a point of view, it works, but the servers of Codewars don't allow more than 12 seconds executing time of code, mine is part of them... Can you help me coding a faster code?

```
#define the function we have to code

def triangle(row):
    while len(row) > 1: #loop will stop when 'row' will be one char length 
        inter = '' #intermediate string which will be row at the end of the while loop
        inter2 = [None, None] #it is a list where the code put the colour letters to be ''calculated''
        
        for i, color in enumerate(row): #'for' loop which make the new 'line' of inverted pyramid
            if inter2[0] is None: #if the first item of intermediate list isn't a colour yet
                inter2[0] = color
            else: #if the first item of intermediate list is already a colour
                inter2[1] = color #put second colour in second item of the intermediate list
                #'if' condition to add letter to the new ''row'' of the ''inverted pyramid''
                if inter2[0] == inter2[1]: inter += inter2[0]
                if 'R' in inter2 and 'G' in inter2: inter +='B'
                if 'R' in inter2 and 'B' in inter2: inter += 'G'
                if 'G' in inter2 and 'B' in inter2: inter += 'R'
                inter2 = [color, None] #make the future intermediate list (so the first if 
condition will not be used anymore)
            row = inter                 
    return row[0] #return the final colour letter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a challenging exercise. To beat the 12 second time limit you probably need to use some combinatorics (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257158/three-color-triangle-challenge) for a very relevant example) and something like [Luca's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem).

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53585022/three-colors-triangles) goes into it in more detail using C, but the principle is the same. In Python, a potential solution could look like this:

```
def get_mapping():
    return {'R': 0, 0: 'R',
            'G': 1, 1: 'G',
            'B': 2, 2: 'B',
            }


def signat(n):
    res = []
    i = 0
    while n > 0:
        n, m = divmod(n, 3)
        if m > 0:
            res.append((i, m))
        i += 1
    return res[::-1]


def triangle_recursive(row, sig, pos, acc, accm):
    if pos == len(sig):
        return get_mapping()[row[acc]] * accm
    
    res = 0
    for i in range(sig[pos][1] + 1):
        acc_part = acc + (i * (3 ** sig[pos][0]))
        accm_part = accm
        
        if sig[pos][1] == 2 and i == 1:
            accm_part *= 2
            
        res += triangle_recursive(row, sig, pos + 1, acc_part, accm_part)
    return res % 3


def triangle(row):
    sig = signat(len(row)-1)
    color_val = triangle_recursive(row, sig, 0, 0, 1)
    
    if len(row)%2 == 0:
        color_val = (-1 * color_val) % 3
        
    return get_mapping()[color_val]
```